# find the value of k at the point P

Tags: calculus

Whilst using this figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5wwo.png)

It's a sketch showing the part of the curve C with equation:

$y = (2x-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$, $x \ge\frac{1}{2}$

The curve C cuts the line y = 8 at the point with coordinates (k, 8), where k is a constant. Find the value of k.

I'm wondering If I approached this correctly?

my workings:

1. $8 = (2x-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$
2. $4096 = (2x-1)^3$
3. $\sqrt[3]{4096}=2x-1$
4. $16 = 2x-1$
5. $\frac{17}{2}=x$ such that, ($\frac{17}{2}$, 8)?

Comment: rewrite your third line  starting by 3).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$8=(2k-1)^\frac 34=2^3$$

$$\implies (2k-1)^\frac 14=2$$
$$\implies 2k-1=2^4=16$$

Comment: Isn't the result the same answer as mine?